# Why is HTML5 Video Buffering so bad in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, browser, html5-video

I've been experiencing a high amount of "random" buffer stops in Chrome when watching HTML5 videos on YouTube and recently on Coursera.org.

The thing is, with a browser like IE10 or Firefox, there is absolutely no problem when watching HTML5 Videos. IE10 seems to buffer the whole video though. Is there a way to enable that exact behaviour for Chrome?

Comment: Interesting question, I have the same problem (esp. if I pause a Coursera video to make some notes).

Comment: This is a very important question. Chrome's buggy buffering for HTML5 video is impacting usability for many video-oriented sites, such as Coursera, but I can't seem to find any other mention of it eg in the Chromium bug tracker.

Comment: Related http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/buffering/

Comment: Npw there is a bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=529690.

Comment: Gee thanks for closing it without even a forwarding topic link .. to discover the true character of a man, give him a little power.